# How to find the character after second vowel in a string in EXCEL?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

For example if my string is

> The Happy Song

The output should be

> p.

If it is a blank, then display "Nothing"

Comment: It would be great if you provided some example of what you have tried to do, even if its completely wrong as it helps people answer the question and increase your understanding.

Comment: Asked here http://stackoverflow.com/q/36978101/641067 as a full question.

Answer (score 2):

Below is my answer. I've also added logic to check if there is a second vowel and if there isn't it throws an error string. See screenshot for details.

> =IF(A1<>"",IFERROR(MID(A1,FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(LOWER(A1),"a","|"),"e","|"),"i","|"),"o","|"),"u","|"),FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(LOWER(A1),"a","|"),"e","|"),"i","|"),"o","|"),"u","|"))+1)+1,1),"no
>   second vowel found"),"")

[image]

Comment: Upvoted. used in refreshed question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36978101/641067)

Answer (score 0):

This will find the letter after the second vowel:

```
=IF(A1<>"",MID(A1,FIND("}}}",SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(LOWER(A1),"a","}"),"e","}"),"i","}"),"o","}"),"u","}"),"y","}"),"}","}}}",2))+1,1),"")
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

Answer (score 0):

VBA answer (with comments) is;

```
Function AfterSecondVowel(InputRange As String)

'Put all the ascii codes for vowels (upper and lower case) in an array
asciicodesforvowels = Array(65, 97, 69, 101, 73, 105, 79, 111, 85, 117)
Dim Counter As Integer
Dim i As Integer

Counter = 0

'Loop through all the letters in the input string
For i = 1 To Len(InputRange)

'Check to see if trying to match the current letter (converted to an ascii code) you are on from the input range
'is in the array of ascii codes - If it isn't this will throw an error
If Not IsError(Application.Match(Asc(Mid(InputRange, i, 1)), asciicodesforvowels, False)) Then

'Increment your counter by 1
Counter = Counter + 1

End If

'Check to see if the counter has reached 2 yet - You can change the = 2 bit here to any number you want to return
'the letter after the N'th vowel
If Counter = 2 Then
'If it has reached the second vowel, skip to the next letter
i = i + 1
'Set the output of the function to this letter you've moved to
AfterSecondVowel = Mid(InputRange, i, 1)
'Exit the function
Exit Function

End If
'Otherwise loop through to the next letter
Next i

'If you reach the end of the letters without exiting the function it's because there weren't
'two vowels so exit the function returning the string value 'Nothing'

AfterSecondVowel = "Nothing"

End Function
```

This will return the values as per your specification, only thing you didn't specify is how it should behave if the second vowel is the last letter - the above will just return an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a data setup like this, with your phrases starting cell A1 and going down column A:

[image: tigeravatar example for Deeksha Jha]

Select cell B1 and with that cell selected, create a named range.  I named it `LetterAfterVowel2` and it is defined with this formula:

```
=MID($A1,MIN(SEARCH({"a","e","i","o","u","y"},$A1&"aieouy",MIN(SEARCH({"a","e","i","o","u","y"},$A1&"aieouy"))+1))+1,1)
```

Now that we don't have to type that mess every single time, it makes the finished formula much cleaner.  In cell B1 and copied down is this formula:

```
=IF(A1="","",IF(LetterAfterVowel2=" ","Nothing",LetterAfterVowel2))
```