# How to find the character after second vowel in a string

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I thought this [How to find the character after second vowel in a string in EXCEL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36923762/how-to-find-the-character-after-second-vowel-in-a-string-in-excel) was interesting, other than being too broad.

Plus I'd answered it but was too late.

*question*

For example if my string is

> The Happy Song

The output should be

> p.

If it is a blank, then display "Nothing"

*possible solution*

One formula approach (courtesy  *tikkaty*)

`=IF(A1<>"",IFERROR(MID(A1,FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(LOWER(A1),"a","|"),"e","|"),"i","|"),"o","|"),"u","|"),FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(LOWER(A1),"a","|"),"e","|"),"i","|"),"o","|"),"u","|"))+1)+1,1),"no second vowel found"),"")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a regex-free variant:

```
Function charTest(s As String) As String
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, r As String
    For i = 1 To Len(s)
        If UCase(Mid(s, i, 1)) Like "[AEIOU]" Then j = j + 1
        If j >= 2 Then Exit For
    Next i

    If j >= 2 And i < Len(s) Then r = Mid(s, i + 1, 1)
    If r = "" Then r = "Nothing"

    charTest = r
End Function
```

Verification:

```
Sub test2()
    Debug.Print charTest("abcdefghijkl")
    Debug.Print charTest("Excellence")
    Debug.Print charTest("Animal")
    Debug.Print charTest("The guppy pond")
    Debug.Print charTest("The smallest bike")
    Debug.Print charTest("Shea")
End Sub
```

> f
>   l
>   m
>   p
>   l
>   Nothing

Answer (score 3):

A possible VBA UDF solution:

*test code*

```
Sub test()
Debug.Print StrOut("The Happy Song")
Debug.Print StrOut("The Gypsy")
Debug.Print StrOut("1234")
End Sub
```

*UDF*

```
Function StrOut(strIn As String) As String
Dim objRegex As Object
Dim objRegexM As Object
Set objRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With objRegex
    .Pattern = "[aeiou].*?[aeiou](.)"
    If .test(strIn) Then
        Set objRegexM = .Execute(strIn)
        strOut = objRegexM(0).submatches(0)
    Else
        StrOut = "Nothing"
    End If
End With
End Function
```

Comment: Add `.IgnoreCase = True`, otherwise words like "Animal" and "Excellence" (or any word with upper-case vowel) get incorrect results.

Comment: @vegard Not sure that would be incorrect as that wasn't specified - useful to point it out though